# File.choose for multiple files R

Tags: r

I have a short script that takes a list of csv files and does stuff to them. 
The problem I am having is that the file names have to be written into the beginning of the file(filenames=c("file1","file2",...)).

I did find [file.choose](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.choose.html) to get the user to choose a file, but I need a list of files.

Is there a way for the user to choose multiple files?

Comment: What's wrong with `list.files`?

Comment: I should clarify, not all files  of the directory should be used;only some.

Comment: For a future use case, keep in mind `list.files`, mentioned by 42-, can be used with a pattern match (regex), so you could use that to filter out only what you want.

Comment: So let the user specify a rule that should be used. ... `list.files` can accept regex patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to install the `tcltk` library and use `tk_choose.files`

```
library(tcltk)
flist <- tk_choose.files()

## Note: to choose multiple files that are not adjacent in the dialog,
##       you may have to hold down the "control" key or some other key.
```

There are a number of options for this and it will pop up an x-windows dialog box (you have to have x-windows installed, which would be something like XQuartz on Mac OS X).

**EDIT**

Note, this is not quite the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227122/r-file-choose-customizing-dialogue-window) but the answer is pretty much the same.