# Allow user to name and select location of exported table

Tags: r

I've got a table called 'resultsHt'. I'd like to prompt the user to select a filename and directory for it to output to. I've had a look round and can't spot an easy way to do it that works on mac and windows. I'd be grateful for your help!

Comment: Try `file.choose()`

Comment: Thanks, but in mac it just asks you to select an existing file rather than select a directory and name your file

Comment: I'm on windows, but it allows me to type in a new file name, creating it if it doesn't exist, and returning the full file path.

Comment: There is also the `tcltk` library, as mentioned here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227122/r-file-choose-customizing-dialogue-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. That looks to work for opening files - it opens in XQuartz. However, it is still trying to open a file, rather than write one. Do you know how to modify this code to work?

```
library(tcltk)
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(resultsHt, tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose X"))
```

**Update**
I've worked out that the following achieves this, at least on mac:

```
require(tcltk)
output <- tclvalue(tcl("tk_getSaveFile")) #User inputs Save As directory and filename
output <- paste0(output, ".xlsx") #Appends .xlsx for write.xlsx function
write.xlsx(resultsHt, output, sheetName="height", row.names=FALSE)
```